# How to configure solr4 with eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, solr, eclipse-kepler

I am trying to configure solr with eclipse kepler.I have done so far is ,i installed run-jetty-run plug-in from install new software menu. I started to follow  "http://eclipse-jetty.sourceforge.net/update/" but im not getting options those are illustrated in these tutorials. so can any one tell me the steps to follow to configure eclipse with solr.
I am new to solr as well as eclipse ,so please bare with me.Sorry if i am missing something to mention.
Following is the screen shot of my project explorer window:
[image: project explorer window]

This is my debug configuration window:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link : http://shrutiags.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/adding-solr-to-your-web-application-part-1-installing-solr-in-tomcat/

This link gives a set by step tutorial on how to setup `solr` in your development environment. It's a 3 part tutorial that will give you whatever you need to run `solr` in eclipse.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion,but the above link is explaining settings in windows environment.I need it from ubuntu.